# Cut, Copy and Paste for all textbox of silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I am working on a silverlight application.

I want Cut, Copy and Paste function on right click of all event.

For this I try below link

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=512

But the problem is that I have to right context menu for all textbox.

Now I am using below link in which create a style of textbox so apply to all textbox of application:

http://codenicely.blogspot.in/2012/04/creating-cut-copy-paste-context-menu.html

But when I try that code I get below error:

> SCRIPT5022: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
>   Code: 4004
>   Category: ManagedRuntimeError
>   Message: Set property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style' threw an exception.

How to solve this error and get above functionality for all textbox

Thanks,
Hitesh